# Invalid ToolChain Submitting IOS App

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

When I attempt to submit to the appstore I get this error:

> Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the
>   public (GM)   versions of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later.
>   Don't submit apps built with beta software.

I am running on Yosemiti 10.10.5 and my Xcode is 7.0.1
My deployment target is 8.0

Any ideas for why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't change the binary and it just worked.  I simply pressed submit for review. It seemed like this was a bug on apples part.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem for one of my build and eventually clued in that the problem was not because I was using a beta version of Xcode, rather that I was using a beta version of OS X (El Capitan Beta 2).  I did a clean install of the latest public release of El Capitan and installed the latest public release of Xcode, submitted successfully (after 6 builds).

Answer (score 0):

It seems apple have a lot of trouble to deal with the different versions of osx and xcode. Don't touch the beta version too if you don't wanna be surprised when you want to send your binaries. For those who have Yosemite I think you forced to upgrade.

For now :

El capitan : build 15A284

xcode : build 7A1001

For those who have for example the last el capitan beta 10.11.1 version and you are also stuck to send binaries due to the last update from app store like I was. Just reinstall the official version from the app store. Apple is lying you can downgrade and you won't lose anything. Many people did it and it solve the issue too. I did it today and Now, I am "back in business"